# Renewed Server Certificate and Crawl fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ssl

We renewed our expiring server certificates and now our search crawls are failing. The error we get is:

> The secure sockets layer (SSL) certificate sent by the server was
>   invalid and this item will not be crawled.

I've read that by checking the `ignore SSL warnings` on Central Admin would fix it but my question is why is it failing now when it was working before? What step did we miss?

Comment: *this isn't an answer but a comment, I could not post a comment because of lack of reputation* Is any of the below true in your case after renewing the certificate: - The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority.
- The name in the certificate does not match the site name.

Comment: No, certificate is trusted and has the same name as the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried that and it did not work. We settled in checking off the Ignore SSL setting in Central Admin. Thanks for your help guys. –

Answer (score 0):

Is the trusted root the same or different from the original certificate?

Export a copy of the certificate including the entire chain but without your private key.

From Central Administration Under Security section select "Manage Trust" and click on "New" to create a new trust relationship.

In the root certificate section - browse to and select your exported certificate.

Click OK - then attempt to re-run your crawl.